# ¿Como agregar un div dentro de otro div?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

tengo un div class="contenedor", y dentro de este quiero agregar dos div class="columnas". Mi código es el siguiente;

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.contenedor {
  border: 1px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}


.columna {
  margin: 0px auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  width: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="contenedor">
  <h2>Este es el contenedor</h2>
  <div class="columna" style="background-color:#aaa;">
    <h2>Columna 1</h2>
    <p>Algun texto...</p>
  </div>
  <div class="columna" style="background-color:#bbb;">
    <h2>Columna 2</h2>
    <p>Algun texto...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Lo que pretendo es agregar las columnas dentro del contenedor, pero con el código que tengo lo que se obtiene es lo siguiente;

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿COMO AGREGO LAS COLUMNAS DENTRO DEL CONTENEDOR????

Soy nuevo en esto, si alguien me pudiera ayudar se lo agradecería muchísimo :D

Comment: No entiendo, las "columnas" estan dentro del contenedor...

Comment: Además, debes poner el codigo como texto, no en imagenes

Comment: @Excorpion Hola, si lo se el código es en texto y no en imágenes, mi error, perdón. Si te das cuenta las columnas están ABAJO del contenedor y no DENTRO que es lo que pretendo hacer :D

Comment: Pon el codigo como texto para replicarlo y mostrarte que estas haciendo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prueba con esta forma, recuerda que el h2 actúa como un elemento de bloque así que se pondrá antes de los demás cajas.

```css
.contenedor{
    border: 1px solid black;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
}

.columna{
    margin: 0 auto;
    border: 1px solid green;
    float: left;
    width: 50%;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <h2>este es el contenedor</h2>
    <div class="contenedor">
        <div class="columna" style="background-color: rgb(177, 177, 177);">
            <h2>columnda 1</h2>
            <span>algo de texto</span>
        </div>
        <div class="columna" style="background-color: rgb(78, 78, 78);">
            <h2>columnda 2</h2>
            <span>algo de texto</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Te sugiero ponerlo en el fiddle para que sea visible el resultado.